# Run same command with different parameters

Tags: command-line

I've a not really permissive program to work with. Unfortunately, this program doesn't just allow the following

```
"command -a -b -c"
```

or

```
"command -abc"
```

So I've to always type the following

```
command -a && command -b && command -c
```

I am pretty sure there is more efficient way to type that, but can't figure it out.

Comment: This will totally depend on the command. Please include it in your question.

Comment: You have many different answers, but I bet you will stick to `cmd -a; cmd -b; cmd -c` in long run, as all human beings do.

Comment: This question is too broad without details on `command`. In general case, `command -a -b -c`, `command -abc` and `command -a && command -b && command -c` have different meaning..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could do:

```
echo -a -b -c | xargs -n 1 command
```

Or:

```
xargs -n1 command <<< '-a -b -c'
```

with some shells.

But beware that it affects the stdin of `command`.

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zargs # best in ~/.zshrc
zargs -n 1 -- -a -b -c -- command
```

Or simply:

```
for o (-a -b -c) command $o
```

None of those would abort if any of the `command` invocations failed (except if it fails with the 255 exit status).

For that, you'd want:

```
for o (-a -b -c) command $o || break
```

That still fails to the `$?` to the exit status of the failed `command` invocation). You could change that to:

```
(){for o (-a -b -c) command $o || return}
```

But by that time, it's already longer than:

```
command -a && command -b && command -c
```

Comment: Thank you Stéphane for this option. The combinaison of !!:0 and xargs did the trick.

Answer (score 10):

You can refer to the first word of the previous command line (`command` in your case) by history expansion `!!:0` and then you can just add necessary arguments to it.

```
command -a && !!:0 -b && !!:0 -c
```

For example:

```
% echo foobar && !!:0 spamegg && !!:0 baz    
echo foobar && echo spamegg && echo baz
foobar
spamegg
baz
```

Note that, as [Stéphane Chazelas has pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254827/run-same-command-with-different-parameters/254829?noredirect=1#comment440027_254829), this can result in unexpected expansions too.

Comment: Exactly what I needed ! Thank you vey much heemayl

Comment: `!!:0` (in shells that support csh history expansion) will expand to the first word of the previous command-**line**, not previous command.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas clarified..

Comment: We don't know what the first word of the previous command-line was. Try to enter `uname` and then `echo foobar && !!:0 spamegg && !!:0 baz`, that will expand to `echo foobar && uname spamegg && uname baz`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks..i did not know that..adding clarification..

Comment: One `!` is enough: `!:0` but with @StéphaneChazelas points better is use `!#:0` where the `!#` mean *The entire command line typed so far*.

Answer (score 3):

How about a shell function wrapping a loop?

```
yourcmd() {
    local arg
    for arg; do
        thing "$arg" || return
    done
}
```

Where "thing" is the actual command you want to invoke. Then simply

```
yourcmd -a -b -c
```

You can even generalize this to any command:

```
splitargs() {
    local cmd arg 
    cmd="$1"
    shift
    for arg; do
        "$cmd" "$arg" || return
    done
}
```

Then

```
splitargs somecommand -a -b -c
```

Answer (score 1):

Amidst the creative and insightful answers, here's something simple in the name of typing fewer characters:

```
# under the assumption that you have a frequently-used set of flags: -a -b -c
alias c='command -a && command -b && command -c'

# slightly more generally, name some aliases according to the set of flags
alias cabc='command -a && command -b && command -c'
alias cdef='command -d && command -e && command -f'

# more generally, just shorten the command name and then pass whatever flags you want
alias c=command
c -e && c -f && c -f
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a shell script **MultiRun**, which takes first Parameter as Command and runs this with remaining Parameters one at a time.

./**MultiRun** curl A B C D

Your Script should take curl as the command and run "curl A" , "curl B" , "curl C" , "curl D".
Now, because your script is in control, you can decide whether a failure in any one command will terminate the script or continue to next Parameter or wait for user input or whatever. You can even decide on the exit status of the whole script, based on the execution of the individual commands.

**MultiRun Script can be something like this:**

```
#! /bin/bash
COMMAND=$1
shift #### Remove COMMAND from existing Parameters
for PARAMETER in "$@" ; #### Process all remaining Parameters
do
  # echo Executing "$COMMAND $PARAMETER" now #### Uncomment this line to see what command is getting executed.
  $COMMAND $PARAMETER
  # Check exit status and take action or wait for user input , if required.
  # read -p "finished executing command. press enter to continue. waiting..." #### Uncomment this line to pause between commands.
done
# Depending on the individual exit statuses , choose your exit status N with "exit $N".
```

Now execute this:
./MultiRun echo 1 2 3 4
to get output of "echo 1" , "echo 2" , "echo 3" ,  "echo 4" like this :
1
2
3
4

**It is a very flexible & reusable solution.**